# JPA Multiple Persistence Unit bug

Tags: java, spring, jpa, multiple-databases

I'm trying to add one more database/schema/persistenceUnit in my project and I'm receiving the error:

`No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2`

I google/api allot and could not found why spring is complaining about my configuration.

Here is part of my applicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactionManager" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="${show.hibernate.sql}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" ...
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryREST" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceREST" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="REST" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${show.hibernate.sql}" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceREST" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    ...
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerREST" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryREST" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="REST"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

---

Some questions:

- Do I need to have two **tx:annotation-driven** ?
- Do I need to specify **persistenceUnitName** in the factory ?

I'm putting some notes of my digg in spring forum ([LINK](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=273072#post273072))

Well thats it... any help will be glad!

Comment: your first entity manager definition wasn't visible, and it was tricky ;) (fixed it)

Comment: give your @PersistenceContext usages

Answer (score 3):

With Spring, you need to have only one EntityManagerFactory.
What you are looking for is describe in the Spring documentation at the chapiter 13.5.1.4 : "Deals with multiple persitence units"

I copy/paste the text :

"13.5.1.4 Dealing with multiple persistence units

For applications that rely on multiple persistence units locations, stored in various JARS in the classpath, for example, Spring offers the PersistenceUnitManager to act as a central repository and to avoid the persistence units discovery process, which can be expensive. The default implementation allows multiple locations to be specified that are parsed and later retrieved through the persistence unit name. (By default, the classpath is searched for META-INF/persistence.xml files.)

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
    <list>
     <value>org/springframework/orm/jpa/domain/persistence-multi.xml</value>
     <value>classpath:/my/package/**/custom-persistence.xml</value>
     <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="dataSources">
   <map>
    <entry key="localDataSource" value-ref="local-db"/>
    <entry key="remoteDataSource" value-ref="remote-db"/>
   </map>
  </property>
  <!-- if no datasource is specified, use this one -->
  <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="remoteDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myCustomUnit"/>
</bean>
```

The default implementation allows customization of the PersistenceUnitInfo instances, before they are fed to the JPA provider, declaratively through its properties, which affect all hosted units, or programmatically, through the PersistenceUnitPostProcessor, which allows persistence unit selection. If no PersistenceUnitManager is specified, one is created and used internally by LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean."

Answer (score 1):

This exceptions means that you are trying to autowire `EntityManagerFactory` by type. Do you have any `@Autowired` annotation in your code?

Aslo, when using `@PersistenceContext`, set the `unit` attribute correctly. And (I'm not sure if this is a proper thing to do) - try setting the `name` attribute to your respective factory name.

Also, check if you haven't copy-pasted incorrectly the REST transaction manager - now there is no such bean `REST`

Comment: No @Autowired annotations in my source, I always use:<br>
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

Comment: the <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="REST" /> - doesn't seem right

Comment: I understand that if I did not specify the unitName when using @PersistenceContext will use the default, take a look in this link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations
look the TIP

Comment: Which one is the default? There are two entity manager factories.
The link you provided is about @Transactional, not @PersistenceContext

Comment: Yea sorry Bozho, actually what I mean to look in this link is about if I need to specify a name in tx:annotation-driven. Sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all of your @PersistenceContext specify unitName.  I haven't figured out how to tell Spring that a particular EMF or PersistenceUnit is the default.  I thought specifying primary="true" on the default EMF would work but doesn't appear to

Answer (score 0):

*Do I need to specify persistenceUnitName in the factory ?*

If you've got multiple persistence units, you do need to specify which ones the factories will use.

More to the heart of the matter, see [SPR-3955](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-3955). To summarize, versions prior to Spring 3.0M4 do not support multiple transaction managers with `@Transactional`. Nor do I believe it honors the "unitName" attribute for `@PersistenceContext`, so you can't specify that either.

For an example of how I worked around this by explicitly injecting `EntityManagerFactory`s and using AOP to re-enable `@Transactional`, see [my sample app](https://github.com/lhanson/multipleEntityManagers)